# MySQL select last 'n' records by date, but sorted oldest to newest

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has transactions with a datetime column.  I'm trying to select the last 'n' records (i.e. 20 rows) but have it sorted oldest to newest.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY table.datefield DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Gives me the 20 most recent, but in the opposite order.

Is this possible in one query, or will I have to do a query to get total rows and then adjust the limit based on that so I can do the table.datefiled ASC and then limit *(total rows - n), n*

Comment: Why wouldn't you do that in your application?

Comment: That's what I'm leaning towards - was just curious if there was a way to do it in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building a SELECT around your original SELECT and convert this to a derived table should do it

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 1=1
    ORDER BY table.datefield DESC
    LIMIT 20
) t
ORDER BY t.datefield
```

Comment: This will work - was looking for something in the query, but I think I'm going to do it on the front end.  Will accept yours as answer though as it does answer the question as posted.

Comment: This is the code I was looking for. I am reusing a node/sequelize method for a "live feed" on the website (datetime DESC) but also an API endpoint for a visualization of the data (datetime ASC). I pass the dynamic limit and orderby as params and assemble the subquery above to get the most recent n records in my preferred order.